# Convert attributed string, to, "simple" tagged html

Tags: html, swift, markdown, nsattributedstring

I want to convert an NSAttributedString, to html like this:

```
This is a <i>string</i> with some <b>simple</b> <i><b>html</b></i> tags in it.
```

Unfortunately if you use apple's built-in system it generates verbose css-based html.  (Example below for reference.)

So how to generate simple tagged html from an NSAttributedString?

I wrote a very verbose, fragile call to do it, which is a poor solution.

```
func simpleTagStyle(fromNSAttributedString att: NSAttributedString)->String {

    // verbose, fragile solution

    // essentially, iterate all the attribute ranges in the attString
    // make a note of what style they are, bold italic etc
    // (totally ignore any not of interest to us)
    // then basically get the plain string, and munge it for those ranges.
    // be careful with the annoying "multiple attribute" case
    // (an alternative would be to repeatedly munge out attributed ranges
    // one by one until there are none left.)

    let rangeAll = NSRange(location: 0, length: att.length)

    // make a note of all of the ranges of bold/italic
    // (use a tuple to remember which is which)
    var allBlocks: [(NSRange, String)] = []

    att.enumerateAttribute(
        NSFontAttributeName,
        in: rangeAll,
        options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired
        )
            { value, range, stop in

            handler: if let font = value as? UIFont {

                let b = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
                let i = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)

                if b && i {
                    allBlocks.append( (range, "bolditalic") )
                    break handler   // take care not to duplicate
                }

                if b {
                    allBlocks.append( (range, "bold") )
                    break handler
                }

                if i {
                    allBlocks.append( (range, "italic") )
                    break handler
                }
            }

        }

    // traverse those backwards and munge away

    var plainString = att.string

    for oneBlock in allBlocks.reversed() {

        let r = oneBlock.0.range(for: plainString)!

        let w = plainString.substring(with: r)

        if oneBlock.1 == "bolditalic" {
            plainString.replaceSubrange(r, with: "<b><i>" + w + "</i></b>")
        }

        if oneBlock.1 == "bold" {
            plainString.replaceSubrange(r, with: "<b>" + w + "</b>")
        }

        if oneBlock.1 == "italic" {
            plainString.replaceSubrange(r, with: "<i>" + w + "</i>")
        }

    }

    return plainString
}
```

---

So here's how to use Apple's built in system, which unfortunately generates full-on CSS etc.

```
x = ... your NSAttributedText
var resultHtmlText = ""
do {

    let r = NSRange(location: 0, length: x.length)
    let att = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]

    let d = try x.data(from: r, documentAttributes: att)

    if let h = String(data: d, encoding: .utf8) {
        resultHtmlText = h
    }
}
catch {
    print("utterly failed to convert to html!!! \n>\(x)<\n")
}
print(resultHtmlText)
```

Example output....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 14.0px 'Some Font'}
span.s1 {font-family: 'SomeFont-ItalicOrWhatever'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt}
span.s2 {font-family: 'SomeFont-SemiboldItalic'; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 14.00pt}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">So, </span><span class="s2">here is</span><span class="s1"> some</span> stuff</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Here, I'll edit the question so it's simpler

Comment: You may want to reorganize your question because it's not clear at all what you are asking and what issue you are having.

Comment: You will need to write your own parser. Whats wrong with the html/css?

Comment: hey @LeoDabus sup.  in any number of situations, you need "tagged" ordinary html fragments.  eg, your server team needs it that way.  its unfortunate there's a number libraries around for this problem if you need "markdown" format, but (as far as I can see) nothing for ordinary old-skool html tags.  it's hard to believe there isn't something in Swift that is less fragile than my handmade code.  You know?

Comment: So you want to discard the font and its size but keep italic and bold ?

Comment: hi @LeoDabus - in a word yes, correct.  you can see exactly how I did it in my "fragile, verbose" code.

Comment: So you want an "HTML document fragment"? Perhaps you should use those terms to search and/or title your question.

Comment: hey @waylan, I sure did search on that, thanks; i think "simple tagged html" describes the type of html document fragment that is needed. (If you think about it ... the complex css in the final "Example output...."in the question, is also a "html document fragment".)

Comment: I got this https://pastebin.com/78Bbs4bH (I'm not a Swift expert, more knowledge in Objective-C) You don't have to keep the range, and do it afterwards in your simple italic/bold case, it's stated in the doc of enumerateAttribute: "If this method is sent to an instance of NSMutableAttributedString, mutation (deletion, addition, or change) is allowed, as long as it is within the range provided to the block; after a mutation, the enumeration continues with the range immediately following the processed range, after the length of the processed range is adjusted for the mutation."

Comment: who, facinating @Larme !! you're saying it sort of adjusts the range as you go, if, you in fact exchange something as you go along!?!?!??  that is priceless man just put your comment in as an answer...

Comment: holy crap.  you even dealt with the case of _both_ bold and italic

Comment: If I understood correctly the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute), in the closure, you can modify the attributed string, within the range value of the closure, and the OS keep a marker at that end of range (that could totally change if you delete the string in that range it for instance, and recalulate the real marker range). Then the next value found, will start at least after the marker.

Comment: that's AMAZING news, and you should put it in as an answer (even if you don't bother putting in any code at all).  Just BTW I don't understand your comment about deleting?  (if you substituute anything, zero to large, it should be fine right?)  Anyway your basic point is spectacular - nobody else knew this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute), especially the *Discussion* part which states:

> If this method is sent to an instance of NSMutableAttributedString,
>   mutation (deletion, addition, or change) is allowed, as long as it is
>   within the range provided to the block; after a mutation, the
>   enumeration continues with the range immediately following the
>   processed range, after the length of the processed range is adjusted
>   for the mutation. (The enumerator basically assumes any change in
>   length occurs in the specified range.) For example, if block is called
>   with a range starting at location N, and the block deletes all the
>   characters in the supplied range, the next call will also pass N as
>   the index of the range.

In other words, in the closure/block, with the `range`, you can delete/replace characters there. The OS will put a marker on that end of the range. Once you did your modifications, it will compute the marker new range in order that the next iteration of the enumeration will start from that new marker.
So you don't have to keep all the ranges in an array and apply the changes afterwards by doing a backward replacement to not modify the range. Don't bother you with that, the methods does it already.

I'm not a Swift developper, I'm more an Objective-C one. So my Swift code may not respect all "Swift rules", and may be a little ugly (optionals, wrapping, etc badly done, `if let` not done, etc.)

Here is my solution:

```
func attrStrSimpleTag() -> Void {

    let htmlStr = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\"> <title></title> <meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\"> <style type=\"text/css\"> p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 14.0px 'Some Font'} span.s1 {font-family: 'SomeFont-ItalicOrWhatever'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt} span.s2 {font-family: 'SomeFont-SemiboldItalic'; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 14.00pt} </style> </head> <body> <p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">So, </span><span class=\"s2\">here is</span><span class=\"s1\"> some</span> stuff</p> </body></html>"
    let attr = try! NSMutableAttributedString.init(data: htmlStr.data(using: .utf8)!,
                                                   options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                   documentAttributes: nil)
    print("Attr: \(attr)")
    attr.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, in: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attr.length), options: []) { (value, range, stop) in
        if let font = value as? UIFont {
            print("font found:\(font)")
            let isBold = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
            let isItalic = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
            let occurence = attr.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
            let replacement = self.formattedString(initialString: occurence, bold: isBold, italic: isItalic)
            attr.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
        }
    };

    let taggedString = attr.string
    print("taggedString: \(taggedString)")

}

func formattedString(initialString:String, bold: Bool, italic: Bool) -> String {
    var retString = initialString
    if bold {
        retString = "<b>".appending(retString)
        retString.append("</b>")
    }
    if italic
    {
        retString = "<i>".appending(retString)
        retString.append("</i>")
    }

    return retString
}
```

Output (for the last one, the other two prints are just for debug):

```
$> taggedString: So, <i><b>here is</b></i> some stuff
```

**Edit:**
Objective-C Version (quickly written, maybe some issue).

```
-(void)attrStrSimpleTag
{
    NSString *htmlStr = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\"> <title></title> <meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\"> <style type=\"text/css\"> p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 14.0px 'Some Font'} span.s1 {font-family: 'SomeFont-ItalicOrWhatever'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt} span.s2 {font-family: 'SomeFont-SemiboldItalic'; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 14.00pt} </style> </head> <body> <p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">So, </span><span class=\"s2\">here is</span><span class=\"s1\"> some</span> stuff</p> </body></html>";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                              options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                                   documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attr);

    [attr enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attr length]) options:0 usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        UIFont *font = (UIFont *)value;
        NSLog(@"Font found: %@", font);
        BOOL isBold =  UIFontDescriptorTraitBold & [[font fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits];
        BOOL isItalic =  UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic & [[font fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits];
        NSString *occurence = [[attr attributedSubstringFromRange:range] string];
        NSString *replacement = [self formattedStringWithString:occurence isBold:isBold andItalic:isItalic];
        [attr replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:replacement];
    }];

    NSString *taggedString = [attr string];
    NSLog(@"taggedString: %@", taggedString);
}


-(NSString *)formattedStringWithString:(NSString *)string isBold:(BOOL)isBold andItalic:(BOOL)isItalic
{
    NSString *retString = string;
    if (isBold)
    {
        retString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<b>%@</b>", retString];
    }
    if (isItalic)
    {
        retString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<i>%@</i>", retString];
    }
    return retString;
}
```

**Edit Jan. 2020:**
Updated code with easier modifications and Swift 5, adding support for two new effects (underline/strikethrough).

```
// MARK: In one loop
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func htmlSimpleTagString() -> String {
        enumerateAttributes(in: fullRange(), options: []) { (attributes, range, pointeeStop) in
            let occurence = self.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
            var replacement: String = occurence
            if let font = attributes[.font] as? UIFont {
                replacement = self.font(initialString: replacement, fromFont: font)
            }
            if let underline = attributes[.underlineStyle] as? Int {
                replacement = self.underline(text: replacement, fromStyle: underline)
            }
            if let striked = attributes[.strikethroughStyle] as? Int {
                replacement = self.strikethrough(text: replacement, fromStyle: striked)
            }
            self.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
        }
        return self.string
    }
}

// MARK: In multiple loop
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func htmlSimpleTagString(options: [NSAttributedString.Key]) -> String {
        if options.contains(.underlineStyle) {
            enumerateAttribute(.underlineStyle, in: fullRange(), options: []) { (value, range, pointeeStop) in
                let occurence = self.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                guard let style = value as? Int else { return }
                if NSUnderlineStyle(rawValue: style) == NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle {
                    let replacement = self.underline(text: occurence, fromStyle: style)
                    self.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
                }
            }
        }
        if options.contains(.strikethroughStyle) {
            enumerateAttribute(.strikethroughStyle, in: fullRange(), options: []) { (value, range, pointeeStop) in
                let occurence = self.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                guard let style = value as? Int else { return }
                let replacement = self.strikethrough(text: occurence, fromStyle: style)
                self.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
            }
        }
        if options.contains(.font) {
            enumerateAttribute(.font, in: fullRange(), options: []) { (value, range, pointeeStop) in
                let occurence = self.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                guard let font = value as? UIFont else { return }
                let replacement = self.font(initialString: occurence, fromFont: font)
                self.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
            }
        }
        return self.string

    }
}

//MARK: Replacing
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func font(initialString: String, fromFont font: UIFont) -> String {
        let isBold = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
        let isItalic = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
        var retString = initialString
        if isBold {
            retString = "<b>" + retString + "</b>"
        }
        if isItalic {
            retString = "<i>" + retString + "</i>"
        }
        return retString
    }

    func underline(text: String, fromStyle style: Int) -> String {
        return "<u>" + text + "</u>"
    }

    func strikethrough(text: String, fromStyle style: Int) -> String {
        return "<s>" + text + "</s>"
    }
}

//MARK: Utility
extension NSAttributedString {
    func fullRange() -> NSRange {
        return NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)
    }
}
```

Simple HTML to test with mixed tags: `"This is <i>ITALIC</i> with some <b>BOLD</b> <b><i>BOLDandITALIC</b></i> <b>BOLD<u>UNDERLINEandBOLD</b>RESTUNDERLINE</u> in it."`

The solutions brings two approaches: One doing one loop, the other doing multiple loops, but for mixed tags, the result could be strange. Check with the sample provided previously the different rendering.

Comment: Totally amazing information - incredible!  Thanks Larme!

Comment: Is there an objective c conversion of this same code?

Comment: @MilanGupta I edited the answer to include the Objective-C version.

Comment: @Larme Thank you so much. You saved lot of my day!!

Answer (score 1):

I have good way to convert **NSAttributedString** into simple **HTML** string .

1) Take **UIWebView** and **UITextView**.

2) Set your Attributed string in **WebView**.

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[yourAttributedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"] baseURL:nil];
```

3) Get your **HTML** string from **UIWebView**.

```
NSString *simpleHtmlString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Comment: Hmm, using "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" is very clever!  I wonder if it avoids all the CSS ??

Comment: Yes, It directly comes from webView. that's while we get only tag without CSS.@Fattie

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more complete solution that preserves more styles and links.

Check out the other keys in NSAttributedString.h if you want to preserve color and kerning information.

```
@implementation NSAttributedString (SimpleHTML)

- (NSString*) simpleHTML
{
    NSMutableAttributedString*  attr = [self mutableCopy];

    [attr enumerateAttributesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, [self length])
                             options: 0
                          usingBlock: ^(NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey,id> * _Nonnull attrs, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
    {
        for (NSString* aKey in attrs.allKeys.copy)
        {
            NSString*   format          =   nil;

            if ([aKey compare: NSFontAttributeName] == NSOrderedSame) //UIFont, default Helvetica(Neue) 12
            {
                UIFont* font = attrs[aKey];

                BOOL isBold =  UIFontDescriptorTraitBold & [[font fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits];
                BOOL isItalic =  UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic & [[font fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits];

                if (isBold && isItalic)
                {
                    format = @"<b><i>%@</i></b>";
                }
                else if (isBold)
                {
                    format = @"<b>%@</b>";
                }
                else if (isItalic)
                {
                    format = @"<i>%@</i>";
                }
            }
            else if ([aKey compare: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName] == NSOrderedSame) //NSNumber containing integer, default 0: no strikethrough
            {
                NSNumber*   strike  =   (id) attrs[aKey];

                if (strike.boolValue)
                {
                    format = @"<strike>";
                }
                else
                {
                    format = @"</strike>";
                }
            }
            else if ([aKey compare: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName] == NSOrderedSame) //NSNumber containing integer, default 0: no underline
            {
            if ([attrs.allKeys containsObject: NSLinkAttributeName] == NO)
                {
                    NSNumber*   underline  =   (id) attrs[aKey];

                    if (underline.boolValue)
                    {
                        format = @"<u>%@</u>";
                    }
                }
            }
            else if ([aKey compare: NSLinkAttributeName] == NSOrderedSame) //NSURL (preferred) or NSString
            {
                NSObject*   value       =   (id) attrs[aKey];
                NSString*   absolute    =   @"";

                if ([value isKindOfClass: NSURL.class])
                {
                    NSURL*      url =   (id) value;

                    absolute = url.absoluteString;
                }
                else if ([value isKindOfClass: NSString.class])
                {
                    absolute = (id) value;
                }

                format = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<a href=\"%@\">%%@</a>", absolute];
            }

            if (format)
            {
                NSString*   occurence   =   [[attr attributedSubstringFromRange: range] string];
                NSString*   replacement =   [NSString stringWithFormat: format, occurence];

                [attr replaceCharactersInRange: range
                                    withString: replacement];
            }
        }
    }];

    NSMutableString*    result  =   [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html>%@</html>", attr.string] mutableCopy];

    [result replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"\n"
                            withString: @"<br>"
                               options: 0
                                 range: NSMakeRange(0, result.length)];

    return result;
}

@end
```

EDIT:
I've added the conditional you need to check to enable/disable underline detection while it's treating a URL.

Comment: `[aKey compare: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName] == NSOrderedSame`: Shouldn't this be simplified into `[aKey equalsToString: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName]`? For the Underline, you might want to test against `NSUnderlineStyleNone`, not `boolValue` (even if it "kind of work", it's a strange test) and misleading since there exists other values.