# Get HTML String from NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

There is a feature in my project where I have to bold the text and save it. Next time when I revisit the screen the bold text should appear.

I am getting bold text with help of `NSAttributedString`. Below is the code for the same:

```
- (void)makeBoldText1:(UITextField *)txtText {
    UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PFIsotextPro-Regular" size:18];
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PFIsotextPro-Bold" size:18];
    UIFont *italicFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PFIsotextPro-Italic" size:18];
    UIFont *boldItalicFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PFIsotextPro-BoldItalic" size:18];

    NSString *selectedText = [txtText textInRange:txtText.selectedTextRange];
    CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    UITextField* textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];

    NSString *text1 = txtText.text;
    NSRange range = [text1 rangeOfString:selectedText];

    NSAttributedString *text = txtText.attributedText;
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutable = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:text];

    NSAttributedString *str = [mutable attributedSubstringFromRange:range];
    textfield.attributedText = str;
    if(textfield.font.fontName == regularFont.fontName) {
        textfield.font = boldFont;
    } else if(textfield.font.fontName == boldFont.fontName) {
        textfield.font = regularFont;
    } else if(textfield.font.fontName == italicFont.fontName) {
        textfield.font = boldItalicFont;
    } else if(textfield.font.fontName == boldItalicFont.fontName) {
        textfield.font = italicFont;
    }
    [mutable addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:textfield.font range:range];
    txtText.attributedText = mutable;
}
```

Now above code works fine but I want to convert it to HTML string with  and all appropriate tags. Once I get the HTML string with all tags, I will save it in Core Data and next time when I revisit screen I will convert HTML to `NSAttributedString`.

The problem is when I try to get the HTML string, it doesn't work. It returns some weird CSS. Is there a way to convert the mutable string to HTML string?

I have tried something like below code but it doesn't work:

```
NSAttributedString *s = _txtCompany.attributedText;
NSDictionary *documentAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute, nil];
NSData *htmlData = [s dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, s.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
NSString *BodyHTML =  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:htmlString];
 NSLog(@"%@:",BodyHTML);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you storing it html string or attributed string?  if you store html string, get from core data when you revisit

Comment: You haven't post how you saved the HTML string. iOS will save it quite verbosely, a lot a HTML, CSS added. If you just want to save a "simple tagged HTML", you can have a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027651/convert-attributed-string-to-simple-tagged-html

Comment: @karthikeyan I am not storing HTML String yet because I am not getting it only.

Comment: If your `htmlString` looks like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>` (there is the rest of the sample on the linked question), it's normal behaviour, that's how Apple decided to save it, and there is nothing wrong with it (it's verbose, but it's valid). Else, you should give us some sample value, and what result you want.

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't do `if(textfield.font.fontName == regularFont.fontName)` (compare pointers), but `if([textfield.font.fontName isEqualToString:regularFont.fontName])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert attributed string, to, "simple" tagged html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027651/convert-attributed-string-to-simple-tagged-html)