# convert attributetext to UTF8 string?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I am getting `\Ud835\Udc13\Ud835\Udc1e\Ud835\Udc2c\Ud835\Udc2d` string from the server.

When i convert using NSMutableAttributedString

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attribute = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[self.message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

It shows perfect **Test** on label as attribute string.

I want to send **Test** to server using UITexView.

I am using following code

```
NSDictionary *documentAttributes = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]};
    NSData *htmlData = [txtView.internalTextView.attributedText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, txtView.internalTextView.attributedText.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It prints HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 16.0px '.SF UI Text'}
span.s1 {font-family: '.SFUIText'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Test</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Extra space in reasulu]

Which is wrong it should show only **Test**. How can i achive this

Comment: That's not HTML in the quote, that's CSS. CSS is used for formatting HTML but it **isn't** HTML.

Comment: @D.Pardal please check updated question

Comment: I think it may be because the `>` character right in the beginning of the HTML code.

Comment: No its not issue

Comment: The output works in Chrome. What browser/program are you using?

Comment: That's normal `htmlData` (the creation method behind it) create that by default using CSS and verbose code. If you wanted for instance only `<b>Test</b>` you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027651/convert-attributed-string-to-simple-tagged-html/44051956#44051956

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)getHtmlColorStringForCustomStyle:(NSString*)customString withBold:(NSString*)boldString italic:(NSString*)italicString andUnderLine:(NSString*)underlineString withColor:(NSString*)color
```

{

NSMutableAttributedString *attStringforCustomStyle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [customString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType

} documentAttributes: nil error:nil];

```
[attStringforCustomStyle beginEditing];

[attStringforCustomStyle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorwithHexString:color alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(0,customString.length)];

if ([boldString isEqualToString:@"yes"])
{
    [attStringforCustomStyle addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                                    value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, attStringforCustomStyle.length)];
}

if ([italicString isEqualToString:@"yes"]) //Put in else if because it does not apply both in single string
{

    [attStringforCustomStyle addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                                    value:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12]
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, attStringforCustomStyle.length)];
}

if ([underlineString isEqualToString:@"yes"])
{

    [attStringforCustomStyle addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                                    value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, attStringforCustomStyle.length)];
}


[attStringforCustomStyle endEditing];

return attStringforCustomStyle;
```

}