# Swift : Regex for remove all inline HTML attributes

Tags: swift, regex, swift4

I want to clear all attributes from an HTML String text. I've found a lot of answers to do that but the problem is the grammer for regex is not working if we don't have a properly CSS style. and my situation was difficult because the HTML text that get from an API is not in order with its style.
It might be like this:

```
<p style="\"text-align:" justify;="" \"=""><span style="\"font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\"=""><b><span style="font-size: 18px;">Angkor Wat</span></b> is a temple complex in Cambodia and the largest religious monument in the world, on a site measuring 162.6 hectares (1,626,000 m2; 402 acres). It was originally constructed as a Hindu temple dedicated to the god Vishnu for the Khmer Empire, gradually transforming into a Buddhist temple towards the end of the 12th century. It was built by the Khmer King Suryavarman II in the early 12th century in Yaśodharapura, the capital of the Khmer Empire, as his state temple and eventual mausoleum. Breaking from the Shaiva tradition of previous kings, Angkor Wat was instead dedicated to Vishnu. As the best-preserved temple at the site, it is the only one to have remained a significant religious centre since its foundation. The temple is at the top of the high classical style of Khmer architecture. It has become a symbol of Cambodia, appearing on its national flag, and it is the country\'s prime attraction for visitors.</span></p><p style="\"text-align:" justify;="" \"=""><span style="\"font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\"="">Angkor Wat combines two basic plans of Khmer temple architecture: the temple-mountain and the later galleried temple. It is designed to represent Mount Meru, home of the devas in Hindu mythology: within a moat and an outer wall 3.6 kilometres (2.2 mi) long are three rectangular galleries, each raised above the next. At the centre of the temple stands a quincunx of towers. Unlike most Angkorian temples, Angkor Wat is oriented to the west; scholars are divided as to the significance of this. The temple is admired for the grandeur and harmony of the architecture, its extensive bas-reliefs, and for the numerous devatas adorning its walls.</span></p>
```

> You can test this string by copy and paste the whole text into [this website](https://regex101.com/) because I want to find the correct Regex that can remove all CSS style.

I want the regex that can work like this [Useful HTML Cleaner Website](https://html-cleaner.com/)

This is before cleaning the HTML:

[image: Before cleaning HTML]

And this is after cleaning the HTML:

[image: After Cleaning HTML]

**These website can clean all HTML attribute and it doesn't care if those attribute is in the wrong format**

I found many Regex on the website that can clean the html attribute but it's not working with my situation: Here are some regex:

- `<[^>]+((style|class)="[^"]*")[^>]*>`
- `<\s*([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\s.*?>`
- `style=\"([^\"]*)\"`
- `style="(.*?)"`
- `<\\s*([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\\s.*?>`

***EDIT***
here is a useful function that can remove the style from Tobi:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "style=\"([^\"]*)\"", options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, html.characters.count)
        let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: html, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "")
```

And the result of this regex is still like this:

```
<p text-align:" justify;="" \"=""><span font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\"=""><b><span >Angkor Wat</span></b> is a temple complex in Cambodia and the largest religious monument in the world, on a site measuring 162.6 hectares (1,626,000 m2; 402 acres). It was originally constructed as a Hindu temple dedicated to the god Vishnu for the Khmer Empire, gradually transforming into a Buddhist temple towards the end of the 12th century. It was built by the Khmer King Suryavarman II in the early 12th century in Yaśodharapura, the capital of the Khmer Empire, as his state temple and eventual mausoleum. Breaking from the Shaiva tradition of previous kings, Angkor Wat was instead dedicated to Vishnu. As the best-preserved temple at the site, it is the only one to have remained a significant religious centre since its foundation. The temple is at the top of the high classical style of Khmer architecture. It has become a symbol of Cambodia, appearing on its national flag, and it is the country\'s prime attraction for visitors.</span></p><p text-align:" justify;="" \"=""><span font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\"="">Angkor Wat combines two basic plans of Khmer temple architecture: the temple-mountain and the later galleried temple. It is designed to represent Mount Meru, home of the devas in Hindu mythology: within a moat and an outer wall 3.6 kilometres (2.2 mi) long are three rectangular galleries, each raised above the next. At the centre of the temple stands a quincunx of towers. Unlike most Angkorian temples, Angkor Wat is oriented to the west; scholars are divided as to the significance of this. The temple is admired for the grandeur and harmony of the architecture, its extensive bas-reliefs, and for the numerous devatas adorning its walls.</span></p>
```

Please use this [Website](https://regex101.com/) to test my given string

[image: This regex can clear the CSS (style=" ") only]

**This regex can clear only the style that in format *style=" "* only**

Comment: didn't i answer you this like 2 days ago

Comment: what is the expected result, ill make provide one

Comment: that's not working! i mean it does clear the style text but still left some unwanted CSS in side the HTML text.

Comment: I will edit the result that left by your last regex in my question again.

Comment: would be great thanks

Comment: i just tested my prev answer its 100% clean, maybe the HTML you have is bad ?

Comment: @Tobi yes! that's what I mention in this thread. because my HTML text gets from the web API. and the CSS style maybe not in order like the string that I just posted. so I want my HTML to remove whatever attribute inside it. The website that i mention can already do that, so i want to know what regex that they use

Comment: alright ill give you a new one ^_^ give me 2 min

Comment: wow haha! thank you so much.

Comment: **Don't. use. regular. expressions. for. HTML.** If you have found many answers then surely you have found many answers that say that regular expressions are incapable of dealing with HTML. You are seeing this fact in action in your own code. Use an HTML parser. For example this one. https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup

Comment: @Tomalak thanks you for recommend this library. I've already used it nowadays. because it parses my HTML text and displays inside the Textview without any HTML tag, I mean is even my HTML text contain the <span> tag to bold the text. the result from swiftSoup will display it as a normal <p> that's why I want to use regex to clean all those attributes and keep the clean HTML.

Comment: Uhm, what? You are missing the point of what the HTML parser does, I'm afraid. You can use it to remove any attributes you want.

Comment: @Tomalak Please provide some snippet that can remove those HTML attribute because maybe I'm not read enough the document that could do that with that library.

Comment: @SopheakSok the regex kindly provided by @Tobi doesn't match `<p style ="\"text-align:"` when there is a space

Comment: that was a different question for good html now i added new code for this one hope it helps :D @Carpsen90

Comment: @Tobi no no, the OP has asked a new question for a reason. They want to remove ALL inline attributes

Comment: Use an html parser, remove all attributes, reconstruct the string back.

Comment: yea i know i just added new regex and new step

Comment: everyone, you can test if the regex is working in this website: https://regex101.com/ it's fast to see the result

Comment: @Carpsen90. the regex that Tobi mention in my last question is working if the format is **style="_whatever_"**. but my case is different because some style is not in the right format as I was mention above in my question.

Comment: @SopheakSok i answered 2 times, on this 1st one to clear all the CSS and someone down voted my answer because he is thinking you need to clean all the HTML tag altho i updated a new one to replace all the html tags please confirm what u want

Comment: @Tobi please try to look at my 2 images above. the first one is the string that gets from the API and the second one is the result after cleaning my HTML.

Comment: Question, what are the HTML tags you "allow" at the end? Are they limited? Else you might be interested with a similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027651/convert-attributed-string-to-simple-tagged-html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) to help you solve this problem. Here is my code

```
    do {
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
        let elements = try doc.getAllElements()

        try elements.forEach { (el) in
            let attr = el.getAttributes()

            try attr?.forEach({ (att) in
                try el.removeAttr(att.getKey())
            })
        }
        print(try doc.body()?.html())
    } catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
        print(type,message)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
```

here is the result

```
<p><span><b><span>Angkor Wat</span></b> is a temple complex in Cambodia and the largest religious monument in the world, on a site measuring 162.6 hectares (1,626,000 m2; 402 acres). It was originally constructed as a Hindu temple dedicated to the god Vishnu for the Khmer Empire, gradually transforming into a Buddhist temple towards the end of the 12th century. It was built by the Khmer King Suryavarman II in the early 12th century in Yaśodharapura, the capital of the Khmer Empire, as his state temple and eventual mausoleum. Breaking from the Shaiva tradition of previous kings, Angkor Wat was instead dedicated to Vishnu. As the best-preserved temple at the site, it is the only one to have remained a significant religious centre since its foundation. The temple is at the top of the high classical style of Khmer architecture. It has become a symbol of Cambodia, appearing on its national flag, and it is the country\'s prime attraction for visitors.</span></p>\n<p><span>Angkor Wat combines two basic plans of Khmer temple architecture: the temple-mountain and the later galleried temple. It is designed to represent Mount Meru, home of the devas in Hindu mythology: within a moat and an outer wall 3.6 kilometres (2.2 mi) long are three rectangular galleries, each raised above the next. At the centre of the temple stands a quincunx of towers. Unlike most Angkorian temples, Angkor Wat is oriented to the west; scholars are divided as to the significance of this. The temple is admired for the grandeur and harmony of the architecture, its extensive bas-reliefs, and for the numerous devatas adorning its walls.</span></p>
```

hope this could help you :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a one-liner regex:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=<\\w{1,40})\\s[^>]+(?=>)", options: .caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, html.count)
let htmlWithoutInlineAttributes = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: html, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "")
print(htmlWithoutInlineAttributes)
```

Given that `html` is this:

```
let html = "<p style ="\"text-align:" justify;="" \"=""><span style="\"font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\"=""><b><span style="font-size: 18px;">Angkor Wat</span></b> is a temple complex in Cambodia and the largest religious monument in the world, on a site measuring 162.6 hectares (1,626,000 m2; 402 acres). It was originally constructed as a Hindu temple dedicated to the god Vishnu for the Khmer Empire, gradually transforming into a Buddhist temple towards the end of the 12th century. It was built by the Khmer King Suryavarman II in the early 12th century in Yaśodharapura, the capital of the Khmer Empire, as his state temple and eventual mausoleum. Breaking from the Shaiva tradition of previous kings, Angkor Wat was instead dedicated to Vishnu. As the best-preserved temple at the site, it is the only one to have remained a significant religious centre since its foundation. The temple is at the top of the high classical style of Khmer architecture. It has become a symbol of Cambodia, appearing on its national flag, and it is the country\'s prime attraction for visitors.</span></p><p style="\"text-align:" justify;="" \"=""><span style="\"font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\"="">Angkor Wat combines two basic plans of Khmer temple architecture: the temple-mountain and the later galleried temple. It is designed to represent Mount Meru, home of the devas in Hindu mythology: within a moat and an outer wall 3.6 kilometres (2.2 mi) long are three rectangular galleries, each raised above the next. At the centre of the temple stands a quincunx of towers. Unlike most Angkorian temples, Angkor Wat is oriented to the west; scholars are divided as to the significance of this. The temple is admired for the grandeur and harmony of the architecture, its extensive bas-reliefs, and for the numerous devatas adorning its walls.</span></p>"
```

Here is the regex explained:

- **(?<=)** : It is postive lookbehind, what is matched is not captured
- **<** : The begining of the opening tag
- **\w{1,40}** : matches any word character, from 1 to 40. 40 is random. This is a workaround since Swift doesn't support variable length lookbehind. If it did, `(?<=<\\w{1,40})` could have been replaced by `(?<=<[a-z]+)`
- **\s** : Captures only tags that have a space after the name tag. (No need to match tags that don't have any attributes)
- **[^>]+** : matches and captures any character but `>`, but least one (Again, no need to match tags that don't have any attributes). This wouldn't be reliable in real-world unsanitized HTML documents, which could have `>` all over the place.
- **(?=>)** : Lookahead (but not capturing) for a `>`

Comment: I tested your regex and it was working perfect but because @da vamp has been posted the answer first with a new way to solve the problem and it was working fine for me. I'll upvote this useful answer so other people might need this too. again, thank you for posting this

Answer (score 2):

It's not so easy as your HTML is completely broken. I recommend you to ask to your API designer why the API outputs this sort of completely broken HTML.

Anyway, if you need to work with this sort of HTML-like something using regex, you may need to detect opening tag and remove everything other than tag name:

```
import Foundation

let inputHTML = """
<p style="\\"text-align:" justify;="" \\"=""><span style="\\"font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\\"=""><b><span style="font-size: 18px;">Angkor Wat</span></b> is a temple complex in Cambodia and the largest religious monument in the world, on a site measuring 162.6 hectares (1,626,000 m2; 402 acres). It was originally constructed as a Hindu temple dedicated to the god Vishnu for the Khmer Empire, gradually transforming into a Buddhist temple towards the end of the 12th century. It was built by the Khmer King Suryavarman II in the early 12th century in Yaśodharapura, the capital of the Khmer Empire, as his state temple and eventual mausoleum. Breaking from the Shaiva tradition of previous kings, Angkor Wat was instead dedicated to Vishnu. As the best-preserved temple at the site, it is the only one to have remained a significant religious centre since its foundation. The temple is at the top of the high classical style of Khmer architecture. It has become a symbol of Cambodia, appearing on its national flag, and it is the country\\'s prime attraction for visitors.</span></p><p style="\\"text-align:" justify;="" \\"=""><span style="\\"font-size:" 13px;="" font-family:="" arial;="" text-decoration-skip-ink:="" none;\\"="">Angkor Wat combines two basic plans of Khmer temple architecture: the temple-mountain and the later galleried temple. It is designed to represent Mount Meru, home of the devas in Hindu mythology: within a moat and an outer wall 3.6 kilometres (2.2 mi) long are three rectangular galleries, each raised above the next. At the centre of the temple stands a quincunx of towers. Unlike most Angkorian temples, Angkor Wat is oriented to the west; scholars are divided as to the significance of this. The temple is admired for the grandeur and harmony of the architecture, its extensive bas-reliefs, and for the numerous devatas adorning its walls.</span></p>
"""
let openingTagPattern = "(<[a-z0-9]+)\\s*([^>]*)(/?>)"
class TagCleaningRegex: NSRegularExpression {
    override func replacementString(for result: NSTextCheckingResult, in string: String, offset: Int, template templ: String) -> String {
        print(string[Range(result.range, in: string)!])
        if
            result.numberOfRanges >= 4,
            case let attrRng = result.range(at: 2),
            attrRng.location != NSNotFound,
            attrRng.length != 0
        {
            let tagStart = string[Range(result.range(at: 1), in: string)!]
            let tagEnd = string[Range(result.range(at: 3), in: string)!]
            return "\(tagStart)\(tagEnd)"
        } else {
            return super.replacementString(for: result, in: string, offset: offset, template: templ)
        }
    }
}
let regex = try! TagCleaningRegex(pattern: openingTagPattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
let output = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: inputHTML, range: NSRange(0..<inputHTML.utf16.count), withTemplate: "$0")
print(output)
```

Seems da vamp's answer is far better.

Comment: Thanks bro for your answer. just use his answer and it's working fine so maybe I don't want to use with regex anymore. but your answer might be useful for other so I'll upvote you too.

Comment: No worries. It's a good example, that when working with complex HTML, regex may not be a good tool. In fact, I would recommend some sort of HTML parsers in a problem like yours. Thanks for evaluating my little effort.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to unescape the HTML, then you can try the following regex to clear all the HTML

> html2 is your html

```
   let escapedString = html2.replacingOccurrences(of: " \\ \"\" ", with: "")

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<[^>]*>", options: .caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, escapedString.characters.count)
let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: escapedString, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "")
print(modString)
```

Comment: i just tested it on playground for the html he has :/ and it worked fine could you be more specific please

Comment: Please do read the question again, and visit https://html-cleaner.com/ to see what the op is looking for

Comment: please copy past my full code and his html and name his html as html2 and try it ^^ it works 100% fine on play ground

Comment: @Carpsen90 sorry didn't focus on the point he said all html attributes, i thought he only wanted to remove the css this should solve the problem, again sorry i just woke up lol

Comment: @TobiI got your back bro. I've upvoted your answer because your answer is useful. but just not in my case. thank you for your participation.

Comment: Currently busy bro I am really sorry but I’ll check on. Later if no one answer and thank you I’ll always try to help

Comment: @Tobi thanks, bro. my college just found out the way to solve this and he'll answer here soon. anw thank you

Comment: Amazing I would love to see the right answer helps me too

Comment: he's using a different technique but it's working though

Comment: @Tobi I've removed the downvote because you've updated the regex

Comment: @Carpsen90 nice of you bro! and thanks you for point out my point