# How do I convert uitextview content to include simplified HTML Tags and ultimately be a string to send?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to send the contents of a textView to a web service, but I want it to include HTML tags BUT the simplified version. See code for details:

```
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: self.textView.text)
let documentAttributes = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType]

do {
    let htmlData = try attrStr.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length), documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
    if let htmlString = String(data: htmlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print("YOUR HTMLSTRING IS: \(htmlString)")
    }
} catch {
    print("ERROR CREATING HTML FROM ATTRIBUTED STRING")
}
```

htmlString is the whole shebang, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"> 
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer"> 
  <style type="text/css">
```

And then the whole HTML, body, class, double quotes tags from HTML. But the web service cannot accept those, especially the double
 quotes I believe is the problem. Android side is able to send only the
 important stuff such as the `br` and the p tags. That's really all I
 need.

So question:

How do I simplify what I'm sending from the whole DOCTYPE html tag to
 the "Test 123 <\br> <\p> Test 123"?

Comment: Here is a sample example of what you can do for bold & italic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027651/convert-attributed-string-to-simple-tagged-html/44051956#44051956 You might need to adapt according to what tags you want. Also, it's strange that your webservice doesn't parse correctly the double quotes, what do you do exactly? Do you do a GET request and put the text in the URL? if yes, you might want to percent escape the characters.

Comment: Based on my previous answer, I'd go with `<br>` replacing `\n`, and add `<p>` & `</p>` for each `NSAttributedString.key.paragraph` found.

Comment: What would I replace "NSFontAttributeName" with in my case? Thanks

Comment: `NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle` which in Swift 3 (I guess that's the version you use), should be `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`.

Comment: I am trying to follow your sample example to work in my case but I am having some trouble. When I use NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, and get a value in the closure, I am casting value as! NSParagraphStyle but then doing value dot property only shows customMirror, debugDescription etc, nothing showing I can check for /p or /br

Comment: Temp version in Swift 4 not totally working: https://pastebin.com/uBtw5BPQ but you should get the logic to get it works in Swift 3.