# Render html in textview, swift

Tags: html, swift, textview, uikit, nsattributedstring

I have this String extension to render html in my textView.

```
func htmlAttributed(family: String?, size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString? {
do {
    let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
        "html *" +
        "{" +
        "font-size: \(size)px !important;" +
        "color: #\(color.hexString!) !important;" +
        "font-family: \(family ?? "Helvetica"), Helvetica !important;" +
    "}</style> \(self)"

    guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return nil
    }

    return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                  options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                  documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
    return nil
}
```

I am trying to make a text bold inside the text view and to be able to export the whole text (html tags included). This is what I've done so far:

```
override func toggleBoldface(_ sender: Any?) {

let string = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.attributedText)
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "FONT_NAME", size: 15)]
string.addAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], range: self.selectedRange)
self.attributedText = string
}
```

But with this the whole text is setted as bold. I also tried to replace characters with html tags but i'm not able to export them since they are NSAttributes (I guess).

---

What is the best approach to make a selected text bold (visually in the UI) and to export it as html once a button is tapped?

For example I have a text view with "Text view example", i select "example" and i replace it with " **example** " so the textview is able to render it, but I cant export the whole text as html (textViewDidChange is also a problem since it replace text).

Comment: `string.addAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], range: self.selectedRange)` should bold only the selected range... That's strange. For the rest, you can go from NSAttributedString to HTML (search for it). But it will be "veborse". You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027651/convert-attributed-string-to-simple-tagged-html/44051956#44051956 if you want "simple" ones...

Comment: @Larme thank you very much!! I manage to solve it with your link!! Thank you veru much.